# Should answers shaped like this be flagged?

Tags: support, flagging

I noticed a strange answer in the shape of *"If you need help, we can help you out at example.com"*

Is it in the zone of validity to post such answer? I would possibly flag as spam since it appears to be promoting this persons webpage.

---

The answer can be found here:

- [Problems with downloading iTunes on Windows 7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/206953)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answers which link elsewhere to answer the question should be flagged, but there's a bit more to it than that.

- Answers which answer the question through quoting content from an external link or providing sufficient information such that if the link is removed *an* answer exists, regardless of quality, don't need flagging. If the content besides the link is thin, a comment may be worthwhile.
- Answers which solely include a link to a page which answers the question, such as example.com/how-to-fix-x/ should be edited to include a quote or summary of the content. If the link is broken, look for a suitable alternative or look for an archived copy.
- Answers which include a link to slightly-related, indirectly-related or unrelated content should be flagged as spam.

All single instances of self-promotion is fine as long as:

- your relationship to the product is disclosed
- it's actually 100% relevant to the question being asked
- it's not a pattern of posting the same links over and over - even if each is correct in isolation.

For example, if I've written an extensive article on my site prior to a question being posted, I will include a link to this content in my answer. However, I will also include a summary of the information such that if the link is later unavailable, the answer is still valid.

Self-promotion can be a fine line if you are just parroting marketing copy without regards to customizing it for the question at hand and you don't offer alternatives to your "solution".

Basically, if it's a 1 reputation user blatantly promoting their own content, flags for spam are generally approved since the OP came here only to promote and not to participate. If a 101 reputation user posts a link to their own content, check their network profile to see if they have the dofollow privilege elsewhere, and include a link to the self-promotion help page if you deem it necessary.

You can always ask on meta or flag as "other" and ask for feedback if a post is spam if you're not sure.

Answer (score 2):

That's definitively flag-worthy, as are all other answers which basically lead people offsite for the details.

Comment: I flagged it as **Spam** since it promotes that webpage